# Sitecore weblog module comment always gets fired

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am using weblog in my website. I have created some blogs, comment section is also enabled in blogs. I have one search box-button in master page, which is working fine on all other pages. But when I am on any blog page and click on search button, the Blog comment part gets highlighted and says that :Fill mandatory fields. (It considers the search button click as form post of comment section). How can we handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `CausesValidation="False"` on your search button.